# Eventos com a tag <select><option>

Tags: javascript, select, onclick, option

Estou tentando fazer uma pagina com html+javascript, porém não sei nada de php...
Enfim, minha duvida é a seguinte!
Tenho criado uma caixa de opções, e quando o usuario selecionar determinada opção, quero mudar um texto...Porém, nao consigo identificar qual opção está selecionada ! Segue o trecho do codigo!

Botão:

```
<select name="tOpcao" id="cOpcao" onchange="MudarOponente()">
            <option id ="cp1" value="p1"><script>document.write("Jose")</script></option>
            <option value="p1"><script>document.write("ola")</script></option>
            <option value="p1"><script>document.write(p1.nome)</script></option>

        </select>
```

Função MudarOponente()

```
function MudarOponente(){
if("Jose" == document.getElementById('cp1').value)
        alert("entrou no if");
}
```

Ele nao entra no if nunca!!! Quem puder ajudar, por favor...
Obrigado!

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo de como deve ficar? Esse "texto" que corresponde a cada opção vem de onde? Já está no HTML ou vem do servidor?

Answer (score 1):

Por que você esta usando blocos de `script` e `document.write` para escrever os `options`? Que comparação você esta tentando fazer dentro o `MudarOponente`?

Coloquei num código abaixo o que eu entendi que você quer.

Estou adicionando o evento de `onchange` pelo javascript pois se o script for carregado depois do `<select>` o `onchange` não vai encontrar a função.

O valor inserido no `<select>` é o valor do atributo `value` da `<option>` selecinada, observe que quando eu pego o `this.value` é alertado o valor adicionado no atributo `value`.

O `this` dentro da função se refere ao `<select>` que invocou a ação, por isso `this.value` para pegar o valor dele.

```js
var selectOponente = document.getElementById('selectOponente');
selectOponente.addEventListener('change', function() {
 alert(this.value);
});

var formOponente = document.getElementById('formOponente');
formOponente.addEventListener('submit', function() {
  if(!this.nome.value) {
    alert('informe o nome pelo menos');
    return;
  }
  if(!this.valor.value) {
    this.valor.value = this.nome.value;
  }
  
  var opcao = document.createElement('option');
  opcao.value = this.valor.value;
  var textoOpcao = document.createTextNode(this.nome.value);
  opcao.appendChild(textoOpcao);
  
  selectOponente.appendChild(opcao);
  
  this.nome.value = null;
  this.valor.value = null;
});
```

```html
<select id="selectOponente"></select>

<hr />

<form id="formOponente">
  <label>Nome</label> <br />
  <input name="nome" type="text"/>
  <br />
  <label>Valor</label> <br />
  <input name="valor" type="text" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
</form>
```

### UPDATE

Veja que coloquei no mesmo `snippet` a atualização com um form para inserir os valores num `<select>`. Com javascript puro fica algo muito "massante". Sugiro que estudo algum framework javascript para te ajudar a fazer isso de uma forma mais fácil como `jQuery`, `AngularJS`, `VueJS`, `AureliaJS`, `EmberJS` e por ai vai, existem muitos haha

Comment: É que as opções sao digitadas pelo usuario! 'Jose', no caso, vai se uma variavel que o usuário entrará... Entendeu? Queria fazer esse select dinamico, não sei quantas opções terão... e depois, pra saber o que o usuario digitou, precisava comparar a string que aparece na caixa do select, no caso acima, preciso comparar a palavra "Joao", com outra variavel... deu pra entender? Obrigado desde já!!!!!

Comment: Mesmo com ele entrando valores, assim não é a maneira mais adequada. Vou te fazer um exemplo de como inserir dados digitados como valor do `select`

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro está na forma de pegar o texto da `<option>`.

```
                                       document.getElementById('cp1').textContent
                                                       |
                                                       |
<option id ="cp1" value="p1"><script>document.write("Jose")</script></option>
              |           |  |______________________________________|
            __|           |______                        |
           |                     |                       |
           |     document.getElementById('cp1').value    |
           |                                             |
document.getElementById('cp1').id      document.getElementById('cp1').innerHTML
```

No seu caso, para pegar o texto na `<option>`, deve-se usar `document.getElementById('cp1').textContent`, ou seja:

```
function MudarOponente(){
   if("Jose" == document.getElementById('cp1').textContent)
        alert("entrou no if");
}
```